# jQuery slideTo with combined attributes

Tags: jquery, attributes, slide

I am trying to target a specific div holding links that would navigate the user throughout the page.

The code I have is:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) { // [id='faqNav']?
    // target element id
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    // target element
    var $id = $(id);
    if ($id.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // prevent standard hash navigation (avoid blinking in IE)
    e.preventDefault();

    // top position relative to the document
    var pos = $id.offset().top;

    // animated top scrolling
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos});
});
```

The `a[href^="#"]` is affecting an accordion I have on the page so I am trying to figure out a way to select the links in the `div` I have. The links are in a list, I thought I'd give the list an `id` hoping that the code would only affect the `hrefs` inside there alone. I tried `a[href^="#"][id='faqNav']` but it affected all `hrefs` on the page.

Not sure how to target this alone. Here's an example of the list I'm trying to target:

```
<ul id="faqNav">
<li href="#link1">A</li>
<li href="#link2">B</li>
<li href="#link3">C</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<li>` Lists items don't accept a `href` attribute which can be used for `<a>`,`<base>`, `<area>` or `<link>`.
The best alternative to use in this case is to add custom data attribute. Like `data-link` in this example

**Solution 1 : following your HTML code**

```js
$("#faqNav li").on('click',function(e) {
    // target element id
    var id = $(this).data('link');
    console.log(id);

    // target element
    var $id = $(id);
    if ($id.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // prevent standard hash navigation (avoid blinking in IE)
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="faqNav">
<li data-link="#link1">A</li>
<li data-link="#link2">B</li>
<li data-link="#link3">C</li>
</ul>
```

**Solution 2: Regular Usage with links**

```js
$("#faqNav a").on('click',function(e) {
    // target element id
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(id);

    // target element
    var $id = $(id);
    if ($id.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // prevent standard hash navigation (avoid blinking in IE)
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="faqNav">
<li><a href="#link1">A</a></li>
<li><a href="#link2">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#link3">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Solution 3 : Data attribute alongside Hash**

```js
$("#faqNav a").on('click',function(e) {
    // target element id
    var id = $(this).data('link');
    console.log(id);

    // target element
    var $id = $(id);
    if ($id.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // prevent standard hash navigation (avoid blinking in IE)
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="faqNav">
<li><a href="#" data-link="#link1">A</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-link="#link2">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-link="#link3">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

It depends on your design requirements, your document Anchors (ids) and your navigation needs. With valid Ids, you can use this to control your page loading too like in yourpage.html#link1 . So priority goes to a valid HTML, then we can customize and prevent defaults...